# Por que essa variavel de instancia nunca assume valor False?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ao rodar o código a seguir, a variavel `_order_stability` nunca fica com valor False, mesmo quando tento forçar durante o debug.

A variável pode assumir outros valores, por exemplo do tipo `int` que sejam diferentes de 0 e 1.

Quando eu rodo o código, a primeira linha da função `insert` da classe `RandomAccessLinkedList` tenta alterar o valor da variável sem sucesso.

Estou usando Python 3.5.2 (default) no linux, mas o erro acontece também no windows.

```
from collections import Sequence


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self._next = None

    @property
    def next(self):
        return self._next

    @next.setter
    def next(self, next_node):
        self._next = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)


class RandomAccessLinkedList(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, *valores):
        self._head = Node(valores[0])
        self._tail = Node(valores[0])

        self._order_stability = True
        self._change_point = None

        nodo_previous = self._head
        for value in valores[1::]:
            nodo = Node(value)
            nodo_previous.next = nodo
            self._tail = nodo
            nodo_previous = nodo

        self._data = [Node(item) for item in valores]

    @property
    def data(self):
        if self._order_stability:
            return self._data

        counter = len(self._data)

        start = 0
        nodo_atual = self._head
        if self._change_point is not None:
            start = self._change_point
            nodo_atual = self._data[start]
            self._change_point = None

        for i, j in enumerate(range(start, counter)):
            self._data[i] = nodo_atual
            nodo_atual = nodo_atual.next

        self._order_stability = True

        return self._data

    def next(self):
        pass

    def insert(self, new_value, index):
        self._order_stability = False
        self._change_point = index
        self._data.append(None)

        new_value = Node(new_value)

        if index > 0:
            previous = self._data[index-1]

            pivo = previous.next
            previous.next = new_value
            new_value.next = pivo
        elif index == 0:
            new_value.next = self._data[0]
            self._head = new_value
        elif index == len(self._data)-2:
            self._order_stability = True
            self._change_point = None
            self._data[-1] = new_value

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index].value

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)

    def __str__(self):
        string = 'Ø → {}'
        string += ' → {}' * (len(self.data) - 1)
        string += ' → Ø'
        return string.format(*[i.value for i in self.data])

    def __eq__(self, outra_lista):
        if id(self) == id(outra_lista):
            return True
        if len(outra_lista) != len(self):
            return False
        for i, j in enumerate(outra_lista):
            if j != self[i]:
                return False
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lista = RandomAccessLinkedList(*[i for i in range(5)])
    lista.insert(5, 0)
```

Onde está meu erro?

Comment: Amigo acredito que seu erro esteja na declaração da propriedade data, logo na primeira linha você verifica se a variavel _order_stability esta como True e retorna o self._data, porem note que logo na inicialização da sua classe você ja inicializa a variavel com True. Pode ser que esteja dando algum problema nesta parte. Outra coisa é que pode ser que esteja tambem gerando alguns loops infinitos nas declarações das funções __len__(self) que esta retornando o comprimento da propriedade e não da variavel, verifique as referencias a self.data e self._data.

Comment: Lembre-se que o acesso a self.data dispara a função getter definida na propriedade data e self._data acessa a variável interna. Sugiro revisar as utilizações da variável.

Comment: O problema é que o insert não consegue mudar o valor de True para False na variável _order_stability. Nem forçando o valor True durante o debug a variável muda.

Comment: Alterar ele altera, veja https://repl.it/EFIT/1

Comment: Talvez o problema esteja na IDE então... valeu @stderr

Comment: Realmente, o erro ocorre no IDE, e somente durante o debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sua `__eq__` chama o len(self) que por sua vez usa a prperty `data` que reseta o `order_stability` - já que você detectou o problema na IDE, o que pode estar acotnecendoé a IDE estar comparando o seu objeto implicitamente, apra fazer as introspecções dela, e isso cause a mudança de estado.

Idealmente, verificar igualdade não deveria triggar código que modifica o objeto - uma modificação local simples seria usar len(self._data)  e não len(self.data)  no seu  `__len__`.  Mas isso não seria o melhor design aí:
O melhor talvez seja disparar a ordenação de forma "sincrona, ao final do `insert` -  e não, deixar arquivado no flag de  `_order_stability` como você quer - (isso evita que acessos de leitura modifiquem o objeto) - se o design lazy for realmetne desejado, tudo bem manter assim - mas então não conte com a IDE que fz introspecçõs de forma automatica azer a coisa certa.

Uma outra sugestão é verificar os [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) e herdar sua classe de MutableSequence - dessa forma automaticamente todos os métodos que se esperam de uma sequência estarão disponíveis, e vão disparar o gatilho de reordenação quando você precisar.

Comment: O lazy foi proposital, usar a property serve para garantir que o objeto está atualizado. Na versão atual, a primeira chamada de um método sempre é pela property, e as subsequentes pela variável. Como funcionam/o que são essas introspecções?

Comment: Essas introspecção são eitas pela própria IDE, e não há como saber o quando e como sao feitas - o melhor é assumir que você não pode ra'contar com o recurso de "auto-completar" de uma die dessas para esse tipo de código, (que gera efeitos colaterais em consuta a properties, por exemplo).}

Batsa usar otura ferramenta para escrever seu código, e usar sessõs inteerativas e testes para acompanhar como está ficando, em vez de depender da IDE automática.